# Algorithm for modulo bitset

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, modulo, bitset

Say I have 2 bitsets

`bitset<1024> test, current;`

How am I supposed to modulus `current` with `test` and output it in another `bitset<1024>`? Note that `test` may be of any form, not just powers of two?

Looking for an answer with either complete code or complete pseudocode. I will not accept answers involving converting to another type except `bitset` because although using bitsets here may work slower, but later in the program bitsets are going to be very fast.

Comment: "Looking for an answer with either complete code or complete pseudocode." -> So, what have you tried so far? The internet contains many algorithms on arithmetics. We are not consultants but voluntaries.

Comment: You need a 128-byte integer, not a bitset.

Comment: @KennyTM: Integers and bitsets are almost the same thing, and I am aiming for maximum speed here. I believe bitwise operations on bitsets are faster than the % operator with integers.

Comment: @phresnel: I have searched but have only found modulus involving integer addition. Don't know if there is a even more low-level modulus than that which is faster.

Comment: @PhoenicaMacia: If you want maximal speed you should use something like uint64_t[16]. A single 64-bit arithmetic operation is often faster than sixty-four bitwise operations.

Comment: The problem is how do I mod the uint64_t[16]? The % operator can be used on single integers, but this is an array!

Comment: Have you also look into libraries like GNU GMP or other arbitrary precision libraries? Have you also looked into division algorithms?

Comment: Could you specify an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try if you don't want to implement the modulo algorithm yourself:

1. Instead of `std::bitset`, use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).
2. Use [boost::to_block_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range) to copy the bitset's bytes to a buffer.
3. Use one of the many bigint libraries to represent a 256-byte integer.
4. Make the 256-byte bigint use the bytes copied in step #2.
5. Perform the modulo operation on the bigint.
6. Convert the result back to a `dynamic_bitset`.
7. Profit

Hopefully, there's a bigint library out there that lets you access its buffer, so that you can copy the bytes from the `dynamic_bitset` directly into the bigint.

And hopefully, the overhead of copying the 256 bytes around is negligible compared to the modulo operation itself.

Oh, and the bigint representation should have the same byte order as the `dynamic_bitset`.